# inline element anchor tag respect padding top and bottom in case of flexbox why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

why inline element taking padding top and bottom in case of flexbox ?

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/pepicuvawu/edit?html,css,output

```
  <div class="abc">
      <a href="">hello</a>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.abc {
  background-color:#eee;
  /* display:flex; */
}
.abc a {
  padding:10px 20px
}.abc {
  background-color:#eee;
  /* display:flex; */
}
.abc a {
  padding:10px 20px
}
```

when I am adding `display:flex` on container then `inline element respect of padding-top and bottom why ?`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is because `display: flex` changes the display property of it's children to `block`. From the specs:

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal.

More information in the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Relationship_of_Flexbox_to_Other_Layout_Methods).

Answer (score 0):

It is taking padding in both the cases but when `display:flex` applied parent div making flex layout of child but not in other case checkout [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) for more information.